# Hibernate search lucene : Updating index document by removing a child entity makes children entity as orphan in index document

Tags: java, hibernate, elasticsearch, lucene, hibernate-search

This is how my entity is configured

```
@Entity
@Indexed
public class Book{

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "book")
    @IndexedEmbedded
    private FrontPage frontPage;

...//other data
}
```

```
@Entity
public class FrontPage{

    @OneToOne(cascade = {}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = Book.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "book_id", nullable = false)
    @ContainedIn
    private Book book;

...//other data

}
```

This is how my integration test looks

```
@Test
public void testMerge_RemoveFrontPage() {
    insertDataSet("dataset.xml");

    Book book = getEntityManager().find(Book.class, 2000L);
    //this book instance already have data

    book.setFrontPage(null);

    dao.merge(book);

    //verify after commit
    //In database the FrontPage entity reference is removed

}
```

By looking at the database, the FrontPage entity is removed but in Book index still, I can see the FrontPage data.

the same thing happens if I tried to replace the FrontPage data like this and in the Book index now I can see two FrontPage data.

```
book.setFrontPage(new FrontPage);
```

By debugging, FullTextIndexEventListener logs below warnings in logs, not sure if this makes sense but I have a suspect that could be a cause.

> org.hibernate.search.event.impl.FullTextIndexEventListener:250 - HSEARCH000024: Unable to reindex entity on collection change, id cannot be extracted: com.x.x.x.FrontPage

Not sure whats going wrong here or is this expected behaviour?

Hibernate versions that I use are,

> hibernate-search-elasticsearch, hibernate-search-orm = 5.11.4.Final

Answer (score 0):

Indexing is near-real-time in the Elasticsearch backend by default, meaning changes take some time to be visible in search queries. By default, it only takes one second.

You can request a refresh after every indexed document by setting the property `hibernate.search.default.elasticsearch.refresh_after_write` to `true`. If you do that, that changes will be visible immediately after a transaction commit. However, this will lead to poor performance, so I wouldn't recommend it in production: just use that for tests.

From the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.11/reference/en-US/html_single/#elasticsearch-integration-configuration):

> Whether to perform an explicit refresh after a set of operations has
>   been executed against a specific index (true or false)
>
> ```
> hibernate.search.default.elasticsearch.refresh_after_write false (default)
> ```
>
> This is useful in unit tests to ensure that a write is visible by a query immediately without delay. This keeps unit tests simpler. You
>   should not rely on the synchronous behaviour for your production code
>   except in rare cases as Elasticsearch is optimised for asynchronous
>   writes: leave at false for optimal performance.

Comment: I already had that configuration for testing scope, still had the same issue.

Comment: Is there any other clue or way to debug and see why isn't updated?

Comment: If you need more information about what's going on in the background, you can enable trace logging for the logger `org.hibernate.search.elasticsearch.request` . This will print out every single request sent to Elasticsearch. You can also put breakpoints in `FullTextIndexEventListener` to see how change events are fired. If you cannot figure it out, create a reproducer using [this template](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/tree/master/search/hibernate-search-elasticsearch/hibernate-search-elasticsearch-5) so that I can investigate what's going on.